# How to see which data is used in an example of a package

Tags: r, statistics

I am using the `library(eventstudies)`([Event Studies Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eventstudies/vignettes/eventstudies.pdf)). In the sample they use:

```
(data(StockPriceReturns))

(data(SplitDates))
(head(SplitDates))
```

However I do not know how to set up my own dataset to use the package. My quesiton is:

How to look into the `StockPriceReturns data`?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: what do you mean by look into ? there are a lot of functions in which you specify the column name of the dataset and then specify "data=StockPriceReturns", and then use the function.

Comment: @sidquanto Thx for your answer! It could be as simple as that..  Sorry for my stupid question.. Pls add it as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to [read a data set](http://data.princeton.edu/R/readingData.html) into a data frame or table.

I'm not familiar with that package, so I'm not sure about required format.  If the data set you read in matches the schema of `StockPriceReturns`, I'm sure R will process it just fine.  This [PDF](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eventstudies/vignettes/eventstudies.pdf) appears to explain it well.

Comment: Doesn't summary or head tell you all you need to know about the data?